# How to change div style when click to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would to change the div css style when click, then change to it primary status when click to another.
i used this code but it just rechange it when click on another div,
here the code am trying:

```
$('.mydiv').click(
function() {

    $(this).stop().animate({
    width:'960px',
    backgroundColor : '#000'
}, 500);
    }, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({width:'300px', backgroundColor : "green"}, 300);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for the [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function :

```
$('.mydiv').toggle(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width: '960px',
        backgroundColor: '#000'
    }, 500);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width: '300px',
        backgroundColor: "green"
    }, 300);
});​
```

And you need jQuery UI to animate colors ?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YGAm5/3/)

**EDIT:**

You're probably still looking for the [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function, but to animate one div when clicking on another div, stop using the `this` keyword and target the div you're trying to animate :

```
$('#someDiv').toggle(function() {
    $('.mydiv').stop().animate({
        width: '960px',
        backgroundColor: '#000'
    }, 500);
}, function() {
    $('.mydiv').stop().animate({
        width: '300px',
        backgroundColor: "green"
    }, 300);

});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YGAm5/4/)

Comment: what i need is to change the clicked div to width:300px when i click on another div

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.mydiv').click(function() {

    $(this).stop().animate({
        width:'960px',
        backgroundColor : '#000'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({width:'300px', backgroundColor : "green"}, 300);
    });
});
```